# Add e-mail adress for SAS to warn when license is expired

Tags: email, sas, licensing

When expiration day is close, only one person receives the warning e-mail message. It's very inconvinient. I want for SAS to send messages to several people. Do you know how can I do this?

Comment: Should be feasible to schedule a SAS program that runs daily, checks how close today's date is to the expiration date, and conditionally emails. How to do it depends a bit on your SAS setup.

Comment: @Quentin thank you for the answer. I try to resolve the problem without programming. Do you is it possible? I found that I can input e-mails in User Manager of SAS Management Console, but I'm not sure that it will work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do it without programming.

Comment: I would ask your SAS representative, they can likely tell you.